How to create a solana token staking program with @solana/spl-token?
I need to create a spl token staking program with the following logic:

The token owner stakes the spl-tokens
We save the price at which tokens were staked off chain
The user can only withdraw tokens when price increases

I have learned that this can be done by using typescript with @solana/spl-token library but don't know how. Can anyone please guide about how I can achieve this or link to some helpful resource. Thanks.

I suggest you create a program for this because using the TS packages for your use case would be too hacky.
But, if you must do it in TypeScript, you would need to hand over freeze authority over the tokens to an ADMIN_ADDRESS and lock them. Locking the tokens means that the owner cannot transfer them to a new address and removing his freeze authority implies that only the ADMIN_ADDRESS can unlock the assets.
Once your price constraints are met, you can implement a method that releases the tokens to the original owner, by unlocking the tokens, and giving the owner his freeze authority.
The glaring problem with this is that, if you lose the ADMIN_ADDRESS KP, all of your users' tokens are also gone.
AGAIN, YOU SHOULD BE USING A PROGRAM FOR THIS!
import {
    AuthorityType,
    createSetAuthorityInstruction,
    freezeAccount,
    getAssociatedTokenAddressSync,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import {
    clusterApiUrl,
    Connection,
    Keypair,
    PublicKey,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    Transaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

const DEVNET_ENDPOINT = clusterApiUrl("devnet");
const conn = new Connection(DEVNET_ENDPOINT);

// owner of tokens
let signer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from([]));

// admin address who will be handling all these operations
const ADMIN_ADDRESS = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from([]));

async function Instructions() {
    let mint = new PublicKey("B4qY7CExMpTRimEFiJR4nx6NsiW9DGMBstFcyNu2xrWK");
    let currentAuthority = new PublicKey(
        "B4qY7CExMpTRimEFiJR4nx6NsiW9DGMBstFcyNu2xrWK"
    );

    // hand over freeze authority
    let freezeAuthIx = createSetAuthorityInstruction(
        mint,
        currentAuthority,
        AuthorityType.FreezeAccount,
        ADMIN_ADDRESS.publicKey
    );

    const tx = await new Transaction().add(freezeAuthIx);
    let txHash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(conn, tx, [signer]);
    console.log(txHash);

    // freeze the tokens
    let freezeTxHash = await freezeAccount(
        conn,
        signer,
        getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mint, signer.publicKey),
        mint,
        ADMIN_ADDRESS.publicKey
    );
    console.log(freezeTxHash);
}

Instructions().then().catch(console.error);



I am thinking about using a program. But I cannot get the price of the token onchain without a oracle (no oracle that provides a token price). So, I am thinking about a hybrid approach where I create a program with stake/withdraw methods. The user will stake and the tokens sent to vault PDA. Then  when the user want to withdraw, I would check the price using a script and then initiate the withdraw process sending the tokens to the owner. The script will have the secret keys of my admin account. This means that I will limit withdraw method to the admin account. Is this approach good enough?

This is a much better implementation. I think some Oracles allow you to create your own data feeds, but I might be wrong.
